# how to put a second pie chart right next to first pie chart inside the bootstrap card

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, chart.js

I am trying to put another pie chart from chart.js, so that there can be two pie charts with different values to be visualized. I tried copying the script two times one for the first one another for the second one but it did not appear [how can there be no pie-chart in the second card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LJdm.png)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var ctx = $("#chart-line");
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ["Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter"],
            datasets: [{
                data: [1200, 1700, 800, 200],
                backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)", "rgba(100, 255, 0, 0.5)", "rgba(200, 50, 255, 0.5)", "rgba(0, 100, 255, 0.5)"]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Weather'
            }
        }
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ctx = $("#chart-line");
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ["Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter"],
            datasets: [{
                data: [1200, 1700, 800, 200],
                backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)", "rgba(100, 255, 0, 0.5)", "rgba(200, 50, 255, 0.5)", "rgba(0, 100, 255, 0.5)"]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Weather'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and here the html code `

```
                <div class="page-content page-container" id="page-content">
                    <div class="padding">
                        <div class="row">
                            
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-header">Pie chart</div>
                                        <div class="card-body" style="height: 400px">
                                            <div class="chartjs-size-monitor" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; pointer-events: none; visibility: hidden; z-index: -1;">
                                                <div class="chartjs-size-monitor-expand" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;visibility:hidden;z-index:-1;">
                                                    <div style="position:absolute;width:1000000px;height:1000000px;left:0;top:0"></div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="chartjs-size-monitor-shrink" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;visibility:hidden;z-index:-1;">
                                                    <div style="position:absolute;width:200%;height:200%;left:0; top:0"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div> 
                                            
                                            <canvas id="chart-line" width="399" height="400" class="chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; width: 400px; height: 500px;"></canvas>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            `
```

Comment: Why are you trying to put two charts in one `<canvas>`? Why not create two `<canvas>` tags and put one chart in each? Also, you referred to a "second card" but there is only one card in your HTML. Also, you don't need to separate `$(document).ready()` functions. Just put all your code in one.

Comment: you should probably create a new question, since I don't see anywhere in your code that you're calling `updateChart()` or using any database functionality.

Comment: yes I shall do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you are trying to show the same chart twice. We can separate out the chart codes into a standalone function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   renderChart($("#chart-line"));
   renderChart($("#chart-line2"));
})

function renderChart(ctx) {
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: ["Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter"],
            datasets: [{
                data: [1200, 1700, 800, 200],
                backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)", "rgba(100, 255, 0, 0.5)", "rgba(200, 50, 255, 0.5)", "rgba(0, 100, 255, 0.5)"]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Weather'
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Then in your html, add an additional canvas below with different id.

```
<canvas id="chart-line" width="399" height="400" class="chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; width: 400px; height: 500px;"></canvas>
<canvas id="chart-line2" width="399" height="400" class="chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; width: 400px; height: 500px;"></canvas>
```